# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 in flutter while trying getting urls from Storage

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I'm trying  **getDownloadURL** from a list of images that I'm uploading to Storage Firebase.

declared variable:   `List<String> _urlsRecuperadas = List<String>();`

Those are my methods:

```
Future _uploadImage(List<File> lista) async {
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

lista.forEach((element) async {
  DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
  DateTime date = new DateTime(
    now.year,
    now.month,
    now.day,
  );

  Reference pastaRaiz = storage.ref();
  Reference arquivo =
      pastaRaiz.child("requisicoes").child(date.toString() + ".jpg");

  UploadTask task = arquivo.putFile(element);

TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await task.whenComplete(() => null);
  await _getUrlImage(taskSnapshot);


});
```

}

---

```
Future _getUrlImage(TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) async {
String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

setState(() {
  _urlsRecuperdas.add(url);
});

_urlsRecuperdas.forEach((element) {
  print("Recovered url: " + element);
});
```

}

---

I can return the '_urlsRecovered' values in the _getUrlImage method.
[image]

But when I try to pass these values on to an object, i got this error: **Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0**

This method is where I try to pass the urls value to an object(In this example, I'm trying to pass just 1 image),

```
 _saveRequest(Destino destino) async {

await _uploadImage(widget.listImages);

String comentario = _controllerComentario.text;
String titulo = _controllerTitulo.text;
Request request = Request();
Usuario usuario = await UsuarioFirebase.getDataLoggedUser();
idUsuarioLogado = usuario.idUser;

request.destino = destino;
request.user = usuario;
request.status = StatusRequest.PENDENTE;
request.comentario = comentario;
request.dataAbertura = date.toString();
request.dataFechamento = null;
request.titulo = titulo;

request.urlImagem1 = _urlsRecuperdas[0];
request.urlImagem2 = null;

FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

db.collection("requisicoes").add(request.toMap());
```

}

I'm trying to solve this for days, if anyone can help, I would be very grateful.
Thanks for you attention

Comment: ```forEach``` is not an async function,so it will not wait for ```_getUrlImage``` to be completed, use ```async/await``` with ```task.whenComplete``` and add ```async``` to ```lista.forEach((element) async{```

Comment: @ikerfah I did what you said, but I got the same error :/

Comment: Could you please update your code?

Comment: @ikerfah Yes, is updated now

Comment: Don't use the ```then```, break it into two lines, ```TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await task.whenComplete(() => null);``` and then ```await _getUrlImage(taskSnapshot);```

Comment: Still got the error, i update the code, like you said

Comment: Idk why is happening, that's the return: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/projetotcc-2a6ae.appspot.com/o/requisicoes%2F2021-02-09%2000%3A00%3A00.000.jpg?alt=media&token=cb3fa03c-9de7-482a-bf6e-1c7f5ff41afe, but the variable continues null